# Windows 10 Navigation Pane with Visual Studio

Tags: windows, registry

I have a .bat script to add a custom folder to the file explorer navigation pane.
I **can** see the new extension, OneDrive and GDrive from **Microsoft Word.** and the default file explorer.
I **can't** see the new extension or GDrive from **Microsoft Visual Studio**, but I **can** see OneDrive and it's own *repo* folder.

So I think there's some settings in the programs what to show depends on the registry keys. 
So I hope there's something key which is missing from the code. Which OneDrive has. :thinking:

```
:: Step 1: get the uids from here -> https://www.guidgen.com/

@set CLSID=82ca13c3-a60c-46fa-b805-fca6dc0cd75f
@set apperance_name=""
@set icon_path=""
@set folder_path=""

:: Step 1: Add your CLSID and name your extension
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%} /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d %apperance_name% >nul 2>&1

:: Step 2: Set the image for your icon
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\DefaultIcon /f /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %icon_path% >nul 2>&1

:: Step 3: Add your extension to the Navigation Pane and make it visible
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%} /f /v System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 >nul 2>&1

:: Step 4: Set the location for your extension in the Navigation Pane
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%} /f /v SortOrderIndex /t REG_DWORD /d 0x42 >nul 2>&1

:: Step 5: Provide the dll that hosts your extension.
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\InProcServer32 /f /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll" >nul 2>&1

:: Step 6: Define the instance object
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\Instance /f /v CLSID /t REG_SZ /d "{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}" >nul 2>&1

:: Step 7: Provide the file system attributes of the target folder
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\Instance\InitPropertyBag /f /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 0x11 >nul 2>&1

:: Step 8: Set the path for the sync root
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\Instance\InitPropertyBag /f /v TargetFolderPath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %folder_path% >nul 2>&1

:: Step 9: Set appropriate shell flags
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\ShellFolder /f /v FolderValueFlags /t REG_DWORD /d 0x28 >nul 2>&1

:: Step 10: Set the appropriate flags to control your shell behavior
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\ShellFolder /f /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 0xF080004D >nul 2>&1

:: Step 11: Register your extension in the namespace root
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{%CLSID%} /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d %apperance_name% >nul 2>&1

:: Step 12: Hide your extension from the Desktop
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel /f /v {%CLSID%} /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 >nul 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Okay**, I figured it out. This is the whole code for adding into the simple file explorer and to see in another program's file explorer.
To see in a **program's** file explorer you need to add the same keys into `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID` this.

**Watch out**! You need to modify the second icon path, because that part can't see the `C:\Windows\..etc` folder.

*After that your cool and ready to go!*

```
:: Step 1: get the uids from here -> https://www.guidgen.com/

:: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{82ca13c3-a60c-46fa-b805-fca6dc0cd75f}
:: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{82ca13c3-a60c-46fa-b805-fca6dc0cd75f}

@set CLSID=82ca13c3-a60c-46fa-b805-fca6dc0cd75f
@set apperance_name=""
@set icon_path=""
@set icon_secondpath=""
@set folder_path=""

:: Step 1: Add your CLSID and name your extension
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%} /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d %apperance_name% >nul 2>&1

:: Step 2: Set the image for your icon
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\DefaultIcon /f /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %icon_path% >nul 2>&1

:: Step 3: Add your extension to the Navigation Pane and make it visible
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%} /f /v System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 >nul 2>&1

:: Step 4: Set the location for your extension in the Navigation Pane
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%} /f /v SortOrderIndex /t REG_DWORD /d 0x42 >nul 2>&1

:: Step 5: Provide the dll that hosts your extension.
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\InProcServer32 /f /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll" >nul 2>&1

:: Step 6: Define the instance object
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\Instance /f /v CLSID /t REG_SZ /d "{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}" >nul 2>&1

:: Step 7: Provide the file system attributes of the target folder
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\Instance\InitPropertyBag /f /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 0x11 >nul 2>&1

:: Step 8: Set the path for the sync root
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\Instance\InitPropertyBag /f /v TargetFolderPath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %folder_path% >nul 2>&1

:: Step 9: Set appropriate shell flags
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\ShellFolder /f /v FolderValueFlags /t REG_DWORD /d 0x28 >nul 2>&1

:: Step 10: Set the appropriate flags to control your shell behavior
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\ShellFolder /f /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 0xF080004D >nul 2>&1

:: Step 11: Register your extension in the namespace root
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{%CLSID%} /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d %apperance_name% >nul 2>&1

:: Step 12: Hide your extension from the Desktop
@reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel /f /v {%CLSID%} /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 >nul 2>&1

:: It will add a copy of it, so it will appear in programs file explorer like Microsoft Visual Studio

@reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{%CLSID%} /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d %apperance_name% >nul 2>&1

:: You need to give a different path to this icon, because this part can't see the C:\Windows\...etc
@reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\DefaultIcon /f /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %icon_secondpath% >nul 2>&1

@reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{%CLSID%} /f /v System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 >nul 2>&1

@reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{%CLSID%} /f /v SortOrderIndex /t REG_DWORD /d 0x42 >nul 2>&1

@reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\InProcServer32 /f /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll" >nul 2>&1

@reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\Instance /f /v CLSID /t REG_SZ /d "{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}" >nul 2>&1

@reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\Instance\InitPropertyBag /f /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 0x11 >nul 2>&1

@reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\Instance\InitPropertyBag /f /v TargetFolderPath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %folder_path% >nul 2>&1

@reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\ShellFolder /f /v FolderValueFlags /t REG_DWORD /d 0x28 >nul 2>&1

@reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{%CLSID%}\ShellFolder /f /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 0xF080004D >nul 2>&1
```